# Functional model in keras: Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder_input' with dtype float and shape [8,64,10]

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

This is the model that I've defined.

```
encoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, MAX_SENTENCE_SIZE, VOCAB_SIZE), 
                      name='encoder_input')
mask = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(encoder_input)
encoded = LSTM(ENCODING_SIZE, return_sequences=False, name='encoded')(mask)

encoder = Model(encoder_input, encoded) 

# make decoder model
decoder_input = Input(shape=(BATCH_SIZE, ))
decoded = RepeatVector(MAX_SENTENCE_SIZE)(decoder_input)
decoded = LSTM(VOCAB_SIZE, return_sequences=True)(decoded)
decoded = TimeDistributed(Dense(VOCAB_SIZE, activation='softmax', 
                                name='decoded'))(decoded)


decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoded)

# make sequence autoencoder
encoder_decoder_input = Input(batch_shape=(BATCH_SIZE, MAX_SENTENCE_SIZE, VOCAB_SIZE), 
                              name='encoder_decoder_input')
encoder_output = encoder(encoder_decoder_input)
decoder_output = decoder(encoder_output)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(encoder_decoder_input, decoder_output)
sequence_autoencoder.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

When I try to train it, using train_on_batch and feeding in input and target of the correct dimensions, it gives me this error:

```
Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'encoder_input' with dtype float and shape [8,64,10]
     [[Node: encoder_input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[8,64,10], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Which doesn't make sense. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Don't use `batch_size" in input shapes. Only the shape of an individual sample of data. (Unless that batch_size is required specifically for the LSTM layer, which I don't understand well). Ex: if you're training with a batch of 10000 images 28x28 pixel, your input shape is just (28,28)

Comment: Removing the batch_shape as you recommended did not fix the problem. I had to remove the `Masking` layer right after the encoder input for it to work. I'm not sure why it solves the issue, though.

Comment: It's hard to give you any more advice without a minimal, self-contained, reproducible piece of code that we can run that exhibits the problem. Here you don't seem to include the code that runs the model, which is very relevant.